# Awk: field not printing to file, but works to stdout

Tags: bash, printing, awk, output

awk noob here.

Fundamentally, I have an awk command, ending in {print $4}, that, when fed to an echo > file command, does not print the value of the requested field. Output is blank.

I'm writing a bash script with the goal of creating a file containing four fields: subject, structure, side, and volume, e.g.

```
136     Hippocampus     Left     3450
```

And I'm drawing from subject-specific files with a bunch of header lines and then a tab-delimited table of brain structures, volumes and other data.

```
12    17    3450    3450.7    Left-Hippocampus
```

The script iterates over these files with loops for subject, then structure and side, and for each combination uses awk to match $side-$struct with the appropriate field in the file, then print the field with the volume. Then it echoes all that data to the outfile.

```
set volume = `awk -v side="$side" -v struct="$struct" '$5 ~ /$side-$struct/ {print $4}' filename.stats

echo "${subj}    ${struct}    ${side}    ${volume}" >> $outfile
```

However, the file always shows the first three columns' appropriate values, but never the volume value; that column is blank.

When I run a sample awk command in stdout,

```
awk '$5 ~ /Left-Hippocampus/ {print $4}' filename.stats
```

It returns the number I want.

Why won't the script correctly print to $outfile the volume data as well as that for the looped variables?

I've seen people talk about buffering speed, and I've tried flushing; I've fed awk the data file with cat; I've tried printing all variables from awk after declaring them with further -v flags; nothing seems to work. Eventually they all do the same thing, print the first three columns in $outfile and not the fourth.

Thanks in advance for any help, this is driving me nuts! The script's been practically ready to run for over a day now...

Comment: Try something like echo "${subj} ${struct} ${side} ${volume} Hello" >> $outfile? Maybe the volume variable is empty?

Answer (score 2):

The `set` command doesn't do what you are hoping.

The Bourne shell syntax for an assignment is simply

```
variable=value
```

with no spaces (use quotes if the value needs to contain whitespace).

So,

```
volume=$(awk -v side="$side" -v struct="$struct" '$5 ~ (side "-" struct) {print $4}' filename.stats)
```

Notice also how the variables `side` and `struct` are now actually used by the script.

However, I'm wondering if you should not be doing all your processing in Awk instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
volume=`awk -v side="$side" -v struct="$struct" '$5 ~ /$side-$struct/ {print $4}' filename.stats
echo "${subj}    ${struct}    ${side}    ${volume}" >> $outfile
```

I've removed the spaces on either side of the '=' sign. I've seen that having a space around the equal sign throws errors when assigning value to a variable

Comment: You should not use old back-tics, use parentheses `var=$(code)`.  Se post made by tripleee.